# Sending message from server and receive from the client end

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream

Here is a sample server program written in c# which receives an id from a client. My sample code is given below. I want to send a string array to client and display is on the client console.
The sample array string can be:

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
```

What additional code I need to add with the following server and client code?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace server
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
      tcpListener.Start();
      while (true)
      {
        TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();

        int recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        string id = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);

        Console.WriteLine(id);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how will i send the string array? @cubrr

Comment: Use a loop and send each element individually or `String.Join` the array?

Comment: Serialize it as JSON or XML?

Answer (score 1):

Since Tcp is a stream based protocol, I would suggest you use something higher level that plain `byte[]`. If all you need is to send strings from client to server and vice-versa, I think a `StreamReader` and a `StreamWriter` on both ends would work great. On the `StreamWriter` side, you've got a `WriteLine(string)` method to send to the client and the `StreamReader` has a similar method `ReadLine()`.

Here's a simplification that you could apply to your model:

Server side:

```
TcpClient client; //Let's say it's already initialized and connected properly
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

while(client.Connected)
{
    string message = reader.ReadLine(); //If the string is null, the connection has been lost.
}
```

Client side:

```
TcpClient client; //Same, it's initialized and connected
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
writer.AutoFlush = true; //Either this, or you Flush manually every time you send something.

writer.WriteLine("My Message"); //Every message you want to send
```

`StreamWriter` will end every message with a new line so that the `StreamReader` knows when the full string has been received.

Note that a TCP connection is a full-duplex connection. Meaning you can simultaneously send and receive data. Checkout the `WriteLineAsync(string)` and `ReadLineAsync()` methods if you want to implement something like this.

If you want to send arrays, establish a simple protocol looking a bit like this:

1. Send the length of the string[]. Example: `writer.WriteLine(myArray.Length.ToString);`
2. Receive and parse this length
3. Send all strings one after the other on the server side
4. Receive all strings in a `for` loop on the client side.

Once you received all strings, repeat the process.

Comment: what about string array? @Philippe Paré

Comment: Sorry I realized that after posting, I updated the question. Having a good base to work on is always a priority in my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

Sending String Array to client

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
        tcpListener.Start();  
        while (true)
        {                     
            TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
            string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
            serializer.Serialize(tcpClient.GetStream(), arr1);
            tcpClient.GetStream().Close()
            tcpClient.Close();

              int recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
               in this line

            string id = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);

            Console.WriteLine(id);

            }               
        }
```

Client

```
         try
         {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            string stringData;

            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234);
            NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();             

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
            var stringArr = (string[])serializer.Deserialize(tcpClient.GetStream());

            foreach (string s in stringArr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            ns.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input), 0, input.Length);
            ns.Flush();


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
        }

        Console.Read();
```